# Creating a calendar scrolling left and right

Tags: android, calendar, infinite-scroll

I'm beginning with android and my current project is building a calendar.
At first I thought to use a horizontal list view but then I can't scroll left/backwards. I've found a tone of information on wrap-around infinite scrolling but I don't think it fully applies to this as the dataset is technically infinite.
Any ideas as to what I should use to achieve this (not necessarily code)?

Obviously I want to use some type of view recycling and be able to go to a particular day(today).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check the link it helps you to create what you want;

https://www.toptal.com/android/android-customization-how-to-build-a-ui-component-that-does-what-you-want

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. I should have been clearer. I'm trying to build one with day views. But this should still give me what I need.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question as this is really just pressing a button and loading the next month. I was looking for a layout where I can swipe left to right...

Answer (score 0):

I use this library, I think it's what you are looking for

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. I'm trying to build one with day views. But the source might give some clues if I can figure it out.